# Serving private images through S3 in django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I am developing a django application that allows users to upload photos and view them and these photos are stored as private in S3. Now everytime I have to show them the thumbnails, i generate a url and give it to the template. This process is really very slow and takes very long time.
I am hoping there is some other way that i havent explored, please help me out. I was hoping for something like x-sendfile, where i authenticate the user and than redirect it to S3. Please let me know if I am missing out anything

Comment: Am I right you're proxying private images via EC2 instance running Django?

Comment: Yeah....i m not proxying, just generating urls. But i think proxying would be a better option. Please let me know

Comment: You mean, you generating temporary authenticated urls to S3? Seems to me the best solution so far...

Comment: yeah...but it's very hectic as generating so many urls everytime is really not good principle.

Comment: I'm doing something similar and I haven't had any performance issues creating the [pre-signed URLS with boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.generate_url).  Are you sure this is where the performance overhead is coming from?

Comment: Right now i on my development server and i think that might be the reason. But you are sure that its not that slow ??

Comment: I can't test just now but I think generating a URL takes less than a 10th of a second per image.  Certainly while debugging it feels instantaneous.  What sort of performance are you seeing?

Comment: Not i m right now seeing very slow creation of signed urls. But the reason may be that my localhost has to send request to S3 to create the urls. But I m anticipating a bit less time when the server will be located in EC2-same region as S3. So I want to know is my anticipation correct?? And is there any other good alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked sorl-thumbnail to make it fast with S3. My code is here [sorl_thumbnail-async](https://github.com/neokya/sorl-thumbnail-async)

But I came to know [easy_thumbnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) does exactly what I was trying to do, so I am using it in my current project. Sorl is not updated since last year, use easy_thumbnails with remote storages like S3. You might find useful my post on the topic [here](http://neokya.github.io/2013/07/please-don%27t-use-my-package/)

[Edit]: sorl-thumbnail now has new maintainers and is updated with latest django releases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail) to serve thumbnails with pluggable S3 backend support and memcached or redis for caching.

You might find this question helpful: [Storing images and thumbnails on s3 in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877497/storing-images-and-thumbnails-on-s3-in-django)

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra fast enough compared to what? to your custom solution? I am sure only you can do the comparison.

Comment: no not custom solution.....i mean in general. How much time will it take to show around 50 thumbnails.