# What is causing this sporadic IntegrityError when calling get_thumbnail in sorl-thumbnail?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto, sorl-thumbnail

I am getting sporadic `IntegrityError` when running get_thumbnail.

I have two API calls: `/listing/create` which creates a listing, and `/listing/mystuff` which retrieves details of all your listings. `mystuff` is run immediately after `create` completes, and `mystuff` is the one that fails on this error.  However, if the mobile app is coded to delay for 2 seconds before running `mystuff` you don't get the error.

In general, then, this seems to happen when you run get_thumbnail soon after the original image has been uploaded.

Full traceback is here: https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/issues/162

There is a suggestion [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=817765) and [here](https://github.com/mozilla/airmozilla/commit/419e7bc470e150295a44e5fe5886ad973b3a071e) to add a hack to try/except on IntegrityError, and to delay a few seconds and retry the operation.  I have tried delaying a long time (10s) and this doesn't work for me.

Based on the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562942/django-s3-boto-sorl-thumbnail-suggestions-for-optimisation) I'm wondering if there is a "first access" problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been fixed on the master sorl-thumbanil branch.
See the discussion:

https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail/issues/162

...and the merged pull request:

https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail/pull/167